# can React useEffect dependencies be "over" exhaustive?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know useEffect dependencies should be exhaustive,
but can it be over-exhaustive?

in my case, I'm creating a component that will measure the dom width after its content changes

```js
const Comp = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const nodeRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    // value is not used inside effect callback
    setWidth(nodeRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  }, [value]);
  return (
    <div>
      <span ref={nodeRef}>value:{value}</span>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setValue(Math.random())}>update value</button>
      <br />
      <span>width:{width}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

demo link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/upbeat-tdd-3jmqq5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A8%2C20

I use `useEffect` to measure the dom width, and because I know the dom will change after the `value` state gets updated, so I put it in the dependencies array. But this `value` is not used inside the effect callback.

is this a good practice?

of course, I can change the implementation to use something like `MutationObserver`, but it looks overkill in my case.

Comment: Can't you call a function that sets the width directly instead of using the value useState? Seems more semantically correct to me.

Comment: I consider this good practice and use it often (when mutating canvas based on value change for example). After all, even though react "doesn't know" that width depends on value, it clearly does. Just add a comment that nodeRef width depends on value, to make this hidden dependency clear.